# An infinite countable bounded subset

Tags: general-topology

Let $X \subset \Bbb R$ be an infinite countable bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
Which of following is true.

$1$. $X$ cannot be compact

$2$. $X$ contains an interior point

$3$. X may be closed.

$4$. closure of $X$ is countable

My Attempt:

I have counter example $\left\lbrace \frac{1}{n} :n \in \Bbb N \right\rbrace \cup \{0\}$ for option 1 and $\left\lbrace\frac{1}{n} :n \in \Bbb N \right\rbrace \cup \{0\}$ satisfy option 3.

Let $x$ be an interior point of $X$ then there must exist an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $x \in (a,b) \subset X$ for $a,b \in \Bbb R$ which is not possible because $(a,b)$ in an interval which is uncountable but $X$ is countable. So option 2 discarded.

If $X \subset \Bbb Q$ then the closure of $X$ is $\Bbb R$ which is uncountable. So option 4 is not true.

So only option 3 is possible. Am I right?

Comment: You cannot take just   any $X \subset \mathbb  Q$ for 4). You have to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Your $X$ for $(3)$ is a fine example and shows right away that it is true.

So you don't have to do anything more than that ("which of the following is true" implies there can be only one good answer and you've already spotted it).

Nitpick: if you insist on refuting the others too: just take $X=\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ as a counterexample to $(4)$ (you cannot take *any* subset of $\Bbb Q$, but it has be bounded and somewhere dense). You're right that any set with non-empty interior is uncountable, not that you need it..